# Counting occurence of elements in a column without naming them specifically

Tags: grep

I have a file called test.txt which has the following structure

```
Tommy 20 School
Tommy 13 School
Tommy 13 School
Tommy 13 School
Mike  22 School
Max   18 School
```

I would like that the second column should be repeated more than two times and print the unique row.
The expected output should be here

Tommy 13 School

How would I do it using grep or awk?

Comment: So what's your expected output in that case?

Comment: Grep first then sort?

Answer (score 2):

If you can use awk:

```
$ awk  '$3 == "School" && !seen[$1] {print} {++seen[$1]}' test.txt
Tommy 20 School
Mike  22 School
Max   18 School
```

Comment: @Joker: can you modify the question instead of asking more questions in the comment?

Comment: The idiomatic way to write that code would be `awk  '$3 == "School" && !seen[$1]++' test.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Given input grouped as shown in your example:

```
$ awk '$0!=prev{if (cnt>=3) print prev; prev=$0; cnt=0} {cnt++} END{if (cnt>=3) print prev}' file
Tommy 13 School
```

or, depending on your needs:

```
$ awk '$2!=p2{if (cnt>=3) print p0; p0=$0; p2=$2; cnt=0} {cnt++} END{if (cnt>=3) print p0}' file
Tommy 13 School
```

If it's not really grouped then just use `sort [options] file | awk ...` instead.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want the repeated rows, uniq is the right tool. But maybe there is some criteria I'm not getting by your explanation.

```sh
cat <<EOF | uniq -d
Tommy 20 School
Tommy 13 School
Tommy 13 School
Tommy 13 School
Mike  22 School
Max   18 School
EOF
```

Output:

```
Tommy 13 School
```

Comment: Yes, I want repeated rows but assume I have other repetitions, for example, two times. But I want to have only those, that are repeated at least three times. So, I would discard the ones which are repeated twice. How would I do it then?

Comment: update your original question with this additional information.